# Three.js PlaneGeometry Fill The Window

Tags: angular, three.js

I am new to THREE.JS and I am trying to create waving flag animation with an Angular project.

This is my progress:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edgwof?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I would like achieve that the plane fits the window height, keeping the aspect ratio and it is placed in the top left corner.

Any advice is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 33

```
this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 5, 30, 50);
```

To

```
let height = window.height;
let width = height * 3/5;
this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height, 30, 50);
```

Then to place it on the top left corner, change the position of your mesh to 0

Comment: Thanks, it works, altough I had to divide the window height with 150, I have no idea what are the units for Planegeometry constructor